# Iterating through FileMaker record set

Tags: php, api, filemaker

I'm new at FileMaker and trying to get data out via the API.
The issue I'm having is when I create a newFindCommand and execute it the resulting record set contains as many rows as there are in the layout but each row is the same. More specifically, each row is a copy of the FIRST row in the database.

E.g. I'm looking for products with a product code like 'XXX', of which there should be 7. I get 7 rows back but each one is the same product.

I've looked a couple of tutorials online and they do exactly the same operations I do so I'm lost as to why my results come out this way.

This is my code for this problem. I haven't been able to track the cause myself yet.

```
$findCommand = $productsFM->newFindCommand($productsLayout);
$findCommand->addFindCriterion('Product Code', 'XX123');
$findCommand->addSortRule('Product Code', 1);

$result = $findCommand->execute();

if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    echo "<p>Error: " . $result->getMessage() . "</p>";
    exit;
}

$records = $result->getRecords();

foreach($records as $record) {
    echo $record->getField('Product ID'); // get the same code for each iteration here
}
```

Any advice?

Edit:
The layout $productLayout mentioned above refers to the Items layout.
Here is a brief breakdown of the ER diagram for the Items table. 
Table: Items
Family ID   Item ID   GUID

Table: Item Options
Item ID   Description GUID

Table: Pricing ~ Item
Family ID   Item ID   Item Option   Qty

Table: Quantity
Qty   Item ID   GUID

Comment: It might be useful to know the tables in the FileMaker solution. What table occurrences are you trying to query and how are they related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this be trying to add the api PHP files again, operating on the assumption I had something wrong. When I added the files and ran the code I got several errors about using deprecated operators at various lines in the FileMaker API.
It turns out several lines use the old =& when creating objects and this was the cause of the errors.
For all but one of those errors you can just remove the '&' and everything is OK.
But for one of the lines (I think it was around line 72), if you correct it by removing the '&' the API will start returning incorrect results. This is where I went wrong the first time around.

The only two options I could see were to drop down to an older version of PHP where the =& operator is not deprecated or suppress the warnings in the php.ini.
I opted for the latter:

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT